# ¿Como acceder varios niveles dentro de un JSON para conseguir un parametro en especifico y usarlo en JAVA?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Buen dia.

Tengo el siguiente JSON:

```js
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [-106.105234, 28.71158],
          [-106.105041, 28.711644],
          [-106.105076, 28.712081],
          [-106.105222, 28.71239],
          [-106.1032, 28.713126],
          [-106.099944, 28.714338],
          [-106.097977, 28.715062],
          [-106.097213, 28.715119],
          [-106.096642, 28.715048],
          [-106.096162, 28.714865],
          [-106.095534, 28.71454],
          [-106.095121, 28.714157],
          [-106.094713, 28.713602],
          [-106.094142, 28.712736],
          [-106.094002, 28.712543],
          [-106.09271, 28.710638],
          [-106.091677, 28.709078],
          [-106.091413, 28.708679],
          [-106.091054, 28.707672],
          [-106.090667, 28.706624],
          [-106.084489, 28.689301],
          [-106.08936, 28.688068],
          [-106.093007, 28.68626],
          [-106.091012, 28.682289]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Base Chihuahua",
        "description": "Ruta Base Chihuahua - Costeña"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-106.105231,
          28.711558
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "marker-color": "#7e7e7e",
        "marker-size": "medium",
        "marker-symbol": "",
        "name": "Gafi"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-106.09168767929077,
          28.682173342499112
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

¿Como puedo acceder a los parámetros del arreglo coordinates?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿deseas obtener el objeto coordinates? ¿haz intentado alguna forma? te sugiero agregarlo tal  vez solo necesitas modificar un poco el código.

Comment: La verdad es que sigo investigando al respecto. Apenas acabo de implementar esto, ya pude sacar los atributos del primer nivel en otra clase, pero ahora que necesito esto de un nivel mas profundo, me tope con pared. Sigo investigando en este momento.

Comment: prueba con `obj['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates'][0] ` deberias obtener los features, el primer objeto, su propiedad geometry(obj), su propiedad coordinates y el primer elemento del array. Todo esto suponiendo que "obj" contenga tu json.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debes revisar la estructura de tu Json para de esta forma poder acceder a la información.

Importante saber:

> - Si el .json inicia con **{**, se considera como objeto Json.
> - Si el .json inicia con **[**, es considerado como Arreglo Json.

En este caso es un objeto el cual tiene un array "features" que contiene un objeto "geometry" y dentro el array "coordinates" del cual deseas obtener la información, pero cada valor de latitud y longitud  se encuentra a su vez dentro de un array:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
      ...,
      ...,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [-106.105234, 28.71158],
          [-106.105041, 28.711644],
          [-106.105076, 28.712081],
          ...
          ...
```

Esta sería la forma adecuada de obtener los valores de latitud-longitud de los array "coordinates" :

```
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(<Definir variable que contiene el JSON>);
        JSONArray jsonFeatures = jsonObject.getJSONArray("features");

        //Obtiene elementos de array "features".
        for(int i = 0 ; i < jsonFeatures.length() ; i ++) {
            JSONObject jsonObj = jsonFeatures.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject jsonGeometry = jsonObj.getJSONObject("geometry");
            JSONArray jsonCoordinates = jsonGeometry.getJSONArray("coordinates");

             //Obtiene elementos de array "coordinates".
                for(int j = 0 ; j < jsonCoordinates.length() ; j ++) {
                    JSONArray jsonCoordenada = jsonCoordinates.getJSONArray(j);
                    System.out.println("Elemento " + j + " Latitud:" + jsonCoordenada.get(0) + " Longitud:" + jsonCoordenada.get(1));
                }
        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Gracias, me funciono perfecto. Ambas respuestas fueron correctas, pero me pareció mas completa tu explicación. Gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Con [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) deberías de poder.

Bajo el supuesto de que tienes un JsonObject llamado node que es donde tienes el JSON entero, de la siguiente forma podrías llegar.

```
JsonElement coordinates = null;
final JsonObject node=//tu JSON
JsonArray array=node.get("features").getAsJsonArray();
for (final JsonElement element : array) {
   JsonObject feature = element.getAsJsonObject();
   JsonObject geometry=feature.get("geometry").getAsJsonObject();
   if (geometry.get("type").getAsString().equals("Point"))
   {
      coordinates=geometry.get("coordinates");
      break;
   }
}
```

Estoy suponiendo que quieres las coordenadas que están dentro de la feature de tipo "point". Dentro del objeto coordinates tendras las coordenadas que quieres.

Comment: Gracias por responder, efectivamente, también tu respuesta fue valida. Te agradezco.